# Routing requests to specific regions/VPCs (Geotargeting)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

We have two VPCs one in US and the other in Europe. Each VPC has a load balancer in public subnets and we run our web application in private subnets. What we want is, if a user visits our website (makes a request to our host/domain) the request gets redirected to European VPC if the user is from Europe region and to US VPC if the user requests from US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route53 can help you with this

Route53 Geo Routing this allows DNS to return different values depending on the place that the DNS request was made from.  See the "Geo Routing" section of this blog post for a good summary https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/route-53-domain-reg-geo-route-price-drop/

You should also look at AWS CloudFront CDN.  This can move static content to a global service that is based near your customer.  So when a customer in for example Australia asks for static files (for example js or css) then these files are actually served from an endpoint in Australia.  You don't have to set up any of the end points you just put the files in an S3 bucket